# How to update Apex Chart data via dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash, bootstrap-vue, apexcharts

I'm trying to grasp an understanding of how to change data in Apex Chart from a dropdown selection in Bootstrap vue.

This code pen link shows that the bar chart works fine with a simple dataset of options and series.
https://codepen.io/tone373/pen/ZEwYxGL

The below code pen does not work.
https://codepen.io/tone373/pen/JjeYazG

I've added a few functions to the computed property with hopes of changing the data in the chart from dropdown list [A,B]

I believe I'm hung up on the countBy and filter (lodash) methods as well as setting up the data set with aData and bData functions.  Am I going about this in the correct way?

```
if (
    this.selectedChartDisplayBy === "a" ||
    this.selectedChartDisplayBy === "b"
  ) {
    countBy = _.countBy(this.aData, this.selectedChartDisplayBy);
  } else if (this.selectedChartDisplayBy === "b") {
    countBy = _.countBy(this.bData, this.selectedChartDisplayBy);
  }

  let data = [];
  _.map(this.barChartCategories, (cat) => {
    if (!countBy[cat]) {
      data.push(0);
    } else {
      data.push(countBy[cat]);
    }
  });


 barChartCategories() {
  if (this.selectedChartDisplayBy === "a") {
    return _.map(this.aNode, "itemIdentifier").sort();
  } else if (this.selectedChartDisplayBy === "b") {
    return _.map(this.bNode, "itemIdentifier").sort();
  }
},
 aData() {
  var chartData = new Object();
  chartData["aNumbers"] = "[13, 20, 7]";
  return chartData;
},

bData() {
  var chartData = new Object();
  chartData["bNumbers"] = "[6, 10, 17]";
  return chartData;
},
  aNode() {
  return _.filter(this.aData, { type: "a" });
},
bNode() {
  return _.filter(this.bData, { type: "b" });
},
```

Comment: You're misusing computed properties. Think of them as getter functions, meant only for deriving state based on other state, such as filtered or formatted data.  They shouldn't be creating completely new data or modifying existing data.  All of these computed properties should be converted to methods and/or data properties.  That is how you create modifiable, reactive data. The select dropdown should run a method in reponse to the `change` event it emits when selecting an option. That method should update the chart data.